# Use a Dynamic Range in an Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a collection of tables with similar names: mytable1, mytable2, mytable3...

I need to create a VLOOKUP formula that uses one table or another depending of the value of a named cell ( Cell "A1"  = rngChoice ) , for example:

```
If rngChoice = 1 then use mytable1
If rngChoice = 2 then use mytable2
If rngChoice = 2 then use mytable2
```

I could use the formula:

```
 =IF(rngChoice=1;VLOOKUP("value";mytable1;"return column";FALSE);
  IF(rngChoice=2;VLOOKUP("value";mytable2;"return column";FALSE);
  IF(rngChoice=3;VLOOKUP("value";mytable3;"return column";FALSE) (...)
```

I can't use this formula because I may need to add or remove tables, so the formula should be changed every time, what's impossible to me.

What I need is something like:

```
=VLOOKUP("value";"mytable" & "table number";"return column";FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use INDIRECT to return the range:

```
=VLOOKUP("value";INDIRECT("mytable" & "table number");"return column";FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: The "INDIRECT" doesn't work for named ranges. It returns #NAME?

Comment: OK tks! I was trying INDIRECT("test1"&"teste2")